# UIButton image in Swift does not change colors even after a function is created

Tags: swift, uibutton, xcode8, imagebutton, xcode8.2

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3, and am trying to create a button that changes colors when I click on it.

the button is black, but should turn blue when I click. The button is an image of a piggy bank.

I went ahead and added an image of the black pig and blue pig, with names `money_off` and `money_on`, respectively.

I am now in the process of writing code to turn the black image blue upon click. The code itself shows no errors, but the simulation was not successful. Clicking on the black piggy bank does nothing.

Does anyone have a clue what might be happening?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
     let step: Float = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var moneybutton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var itemTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func moneyClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.currentImage === #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money_off"){
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "money_on"), for: .normal)}
        else {
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "money_off"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked with breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var moneybutton: UIButton!

  func viewDidLoad() {
    self.moneybutton.setImage(UIImage(named:"money_on"), for: .selected)
    self.moneybutton.setImage(UIImage(named:"money_off"), for: .normal)
  }

  @IBAction func moneyClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
   self.moneybutton.isSelected = !self.moneybutton.isSelected
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better not rely on the return value of some `#imageLiteral`, but instead keep a state, like `moneyOff` in the example code below.

(sorry, no Xcode available, so code might contain some syntax errors, but you'll get the idea):

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    let step: Float = 1
    var moneyOff = true

    @IBOutlet weak var moneybutton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var itemTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func moneyClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if moneyOff {
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "money_on"), for: .normal)}
        else {
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "money_off"), for: .normal)
        }
        moneyOff = !moneyOff // toggle state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is work for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var moneybutton: UIButton!
     func viewDidLoad() 
     {
       moneybutton.setImage(UIImage(named:"money_on"), for: .selected)
       moneybutton.setImage(UIImage(named:"money_off"), for: .normal)
     }

     @IBAction func moneyClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
     {
       if self.btn.isSelected
       {
         self.moneybutton.isSelected = false
       }
       else{
         self.moneybutton.isSelected = true
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is your connection between *storyboard* and *view controller*.

I try to add button programmatically and it work.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var btn: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClicked)))
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "money_off"), for: .normal)

        return btn
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        view.addSubview(btn)

        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        btn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true

    }

    func handleClicked() {
        if btn.currentImage == UIImage(named: "money_off")  {
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "money_on"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "money_off"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```